# how to display the output of a for loop as a list and then append it to another list?

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I've found and appended the divisors of numbers in a range into a list and now I have the output: [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5] but  I need each sequence of divisors as a separated list such [[1],[1], [1], [1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2, 5]]. How can I achieve this output? my code so far is below:

```
lis1=[1]
lis2=[]
s=0
for i in range(2, 11):
    lis1.append(i)
    for j in range(1,i):
        if i % j == 0:
            lis2.append(j)

print(lis1)
print(lis2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@spill1 already gave the exact answer I would have written, so just for the sake of variety, here's a way you can do it in one line with nested list comprehensions:

```
[[y for y in range(1, x) if not x % y] for x in range(2, 11)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create an empty list before the inner loop, then append that list to `lis2` after you complete the inner loop.

```
lis1=[1]
lis2=[]
s=0
for i in range(2, 11):
    lis1.append(i)
    list_j = []
    for j in range(1,i):
        if i % j == 0:
            list_j.append(j)
    lis2.append(list_j)
print(lis1)
print(lis2)
```